# How to return sepcyfic type function in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the old code. I have two classes. One is responsible for validating the field and the other adds the value to the database if the field has passed validation.
I want each function to return a specific type. But when, for example, I assigned: string to the validateschool function, the program does not work. Someone might say why.

```
class SchoolUpdating
{
   private $database;
   private $data;
   private $schoolValidation;

    public function __construct($database, $data,  $schoolValidation)
    {
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->schoolValidation =  $schoolValidation;
    }

    public function UpdateSchool(): string
    {
        if(empty($this->schoolValidation->getError())) {
            $school = htmlspecialchars($this->data["school"]);
            $session = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id']);

            $query = $this->database->ConnectDatabase()->prepare("UPDATE user set school = :school where user_id = :id");
            $query->bindParam(':school', $school, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':id', $session, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

```js
class SchoolValidation
{
    private string $data;
    private $database;
    private string $error = '';


    public function __construct($database, $data)
    {
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getError(): string
    {
        return $this->error;
    }

    public function ValidateSchool(): string
    {

        $val = htmlspecialchars($this->data['school']);

        if(empty($val))
        {
            return $this->error = "Podaj szkole";
        }else if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\-\s]+$/', $val))
        {
            return $this->error = "Nieporawny format";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never call `$this->schoolValidation->ValidateSchool()`

Comment: `UpdateSchool()` has no `return` statement. It's supposed to return a string. What is that string supposed to be?

Comment: UpdateSchool() only add date to a database, so a type should be void in my opinion

Comment: Then why did you declare it to return a string?

Comment: `ValidateSchool()` doesn't return anything if neither of the `if` conditions is true. It should return an empty string.

Comment: It should also do `$this->error = "";` to clear the error property.

Comment: 'public function UpdateSchool(): void'  thats correct now ?